# InstallShield exe should silently start specific exe after installation

Tags: c#, command-line, windows-installer, installshield

**my issue:**
The goal is, that some exe-files will be started after installation of a Install Shield exe.
The InstallShield program includes the exe-files that have to be started.
All of these steps have to be without UI and user interaction.

The InstallShield-exe includes the configuraton, that after the last step, specific exe-files will be started.

All of that works fine If I **don't** use parameters for silent installation. (**setup.exe /s /v/qr)**. If I use this command line parameters, only the program itself will be installed (The directory within the programfiles and the program name within the installed program and features appears). BUT **none** of the exe-files starts.

**my question:** So, what parameters I have to use for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have added custom actions to start your executables somewhere in the UI sequence (perhaps on the final page of the wizard). However when you run silent installations, the entire UI sequence is skipped.

In order to launch the executables in this case, you'll need to add custom actions to the execute sequence. In order to ensure the exe doesn't launch before the wizard is exited or to avoid launching them twice if you leave the UI sequence actions, you'll want to condition the execute sequence actions so they only run in silent cases; I'd suggest referencing [UILevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372096.aspx) for the condition.

Comment: I add custom actions during installation (after setup complete success dialog / after register product). Both of it result in the situation described above.

What do you exactly mean with "add custom action to the execute sequence"?

Comment: InstallShield should have some way to say you want a CA in the execute sequence. You may need to look at the docs - IS may refer to them as deferred CAs as opposed to immediate, something like that.

Comment: @FabianSeitz It sounds like you're using the Express or Limited edition. Neither of those editions give you full access to the sequences, or conditions for that matter, so this advice is hard to apply there. I suggest in the future you clarify your edition in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the limited edition. Sorry for don't clarify that before. I assumed that such a easy condition will be available also in my edition... Think again.